# kasan1及びsample44のエラーについて

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class sample44{
 public static void main(String[] args){

   kasan1 obj1 = new kasan1();
   obj1.a = 10;
   obj1.b = 20;
   int ans1 = obj1.tasu(10,20);
   System.out.println(ans1);

   kasan1 obj2 = new kasan1();
   obj2.a = 30;
   obj2.b = 40;
   int ans2 = obj2.tasu(30,40);
   System.out.println(ans2);
   }
}
```

kasan1

```
class kasan1{

//  int a;
//  int b;
    int c;

  void tasu(int a, int b){
   int c = a + b;
   return c;
 }
}
```

cmdでのエラー

sample44.java:6: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません    obj1.a = 10;
       ^   シンボル:   変数 a   場所: タイプkasan1の変数 obj1 sample44.java:7: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません    obj1.b = 20;
       ^   シンボル:   変数 b   場所: タイプkasan1の変数 obj1 sample44.java:8: エラー: 互換性のない型    int ans1 = obj1.tasu(10,20);
                       ^   期待値: int   検出値:    void sample44.java:12: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません    obj2.a = 30;
       ^   シンボル:   変数 a   場所: タイプkasan1の変数 obj2 sample44.java:13: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません    obj2.b = 40;
       ^   シンボル:   変数 b   場所: タイプkasan1の変数 obj2 sample44.java:14: エラー: 互換性のない型    int ans2 = obj2.tasu(30,40);
                       ^   期待値: int   検出値:    void .\kasan1.java:9: エラー: 戻り値の型がvoidのメソッドからは値を返せません    return c;
          ^ エラー:7個

どこが問題なんでしょうか？

わかる方お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `a` と `b` がコメントアウトされている。

   ```
   //  int a;
   //  int b;
   ```

   コメントをはずす

   ```
   int a;
   int b;
   ```
2. `void tasu(int a, int b){` で、メソッド`tasu` が期待される返値は`int`なのに`void`で「値を返さない」となっている。

   `int` に変更する

   ```
   int tasu(int a, int b){
   ```